# JsonValidationError(List(error.expected.jsobject) while parsing object

Tags: scala, playframework, play-json

I parsed object to Json in my writes method, but got an error
***JsonValidationError(List(error.expected.jsobject)***

```
override def writes(o: UploadedFile): JsValue = JsObject(
  Seq("path" -> JsString(o.path.toString), "content" -> JsString(Json.stringify(Json.toJson(o.content))))
)
```

UploadedFile.fileContent - is an object to as UploadedFile and has its own implicit formatter,

```
final case class UploadedFileContent(content: String)

object UploadedFileContent {
  implicit val uploadedFileContentFormat: OFormat[UploadedFileContent] = Json.format[UploadedFileContent]
}
```

and UploadedFile formatter:

```
object UploadedFile {

  implicit object UploadedFileFormat extends Format[UploadedFile] {
    override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[UploadedFile] =
      JsSuccess(
        UploadedFile(Paths.get((json \ "path").as[String]), (json \ "content").as[UploadedFileContent])
      )

    override def writes(o: UploadedFile): JsValue = JsObject(
      Seq("path" -> JsString(o.path.toString), "content" -> JsString(Json.stringify(Json.toJson(o.content))))//error is smw here
    )
  }
}
```

Maybe I need something instead of 
Json.stringify(Json.toJson(o.content))
in my writes method, but I don't know what exactly. Tried a lot variants

Answer (score 1):

If `UploadedFile` is a case class:

```
implicit val format: OFormat[UploadedFile] = Json.format
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  implicit lazy val UploadedFileFormat: OFormat[UploadedFile] = {
    ((JsPath \ "path").format[Path] ~ (JsPath \ "content")
      .format[UploadedFileContent])(UploadedFile.apply, unlift(UploadedFile.unapply))
  }
```